# Laravel 4 CSRF form submit through Ajax call

Tags: jquery, laravel-4, csrf

I'm new to both Stackoverflow and Laravel 4,
I am trying to submit a form through jquery ajax. I serializeArray() the form and use json to submit it. 
In laravel, in the routes I check the csrf token submitted, the go to my controller for process inputs.
The csrf check doesn't work when the _token input is in an array as with serializeArray(). 
I have to get the _token value and submit is as a seperate ajax data. I'm wondering if there is a way to tell csrf filter where ever its running to check the input array for hte field _token and use that? 
here is my code:

routes.php

```
Route::post('searchAjax', array('before' => 'csrf', 
                                'uses' => 'SearchController@searchAjax'));
```

This is where I wan't it to read the array form[0]['_token] but I don't know how to tell it to do that.

```
index.js
    var form = $('#search').serializeArray();
var token = $('#search > input[name="_token"]').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'searchAjax',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { _token: token, form: form },
    success: function(data) {
        for(var key in data)
        {
            //alert(key)
        }
        //alert(data.message);
    }
});
```

I want to get rid of  { _token: token, form: form } in the ajax call and just have 'form' that is an array with _token in it already.
here is the html:

```
<form id="search" class="form-horizontal" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://testing:998/search" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" value="6GBbv9LmnOdL8UcOsm8DDJ4Bfi6eGcQRlC9SPdL4" name="_token">
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="title">Book Titles</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="title" class="input" type="text" value="click to search book titles" name="title">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<div class="control-group">
<div class="control-group">
</form>
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: what is wrong with `data: { _token: token, form: form }` and what do you want ?

Comment: nothing is wrong with it, but form already contains _token. I was merely trying to make my code simpler and see if there is a way to access the Route:: to execute a function before and then link to a controller.

Comment: Your question is confusing, can you rephrase it ?

Answer (score 28):

Another option is to use the approach outlined by  Kelt Dockins  which is to send the token in the headers using jquery, eg. somewhere in your jquery/javascript bootstrapping add:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

This will get the CSRF token from a header meta data tag and include it in the headers of each ajax request. Then you need to add the metadata and token into your Laravel templates, eg.

```
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="<?= csrf_token() ?>">
```

You also need to modify the CSRF filter to check the ajax request header as well the default Input::get('_token')

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()

{
   $token = Request::ajax() ? Request::header('X-CSRF-Token') : Input::get('_token');
   if (Session::token() != $token) {
      throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
   }
});
```

Comment: @Wistar the link is live again and here is the link to follow up post (you should read this too as it improves security aspect) http://keltdockins.com/2013/12/12/csrf-token-protection-in-laravel/

Comment: @Danny I noticed. Forgot to erase my comment.

Comment: Also note the vulnerability discovered with the CSRF filter in Laravel 4: http://blog.laravel.com/csrf-vulnerability-in-laravel-4/

Comment: Please note, all suggested links are broken.