# How to erase a single record in Laravel using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have being searching everywhere for the past 6 hours and I can't find the answer to my question. I have a data table that display a list of users. I have an column that has an icon that looks like a trash can. The idea is when a user press the icon that  gets erase using ajax. This is my first time using ajax and laravel.

This is my view

```
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="destroy" data-id="5"><i class="fa   fa-trash-o "></i>
    </button>
</td>
```

This is my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#destroy").click(function()
    {

        var id = $(this).data("id");

        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "http://localhost:8888/users/destroy",
            type: 'DELETE',
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {
                "id": id
            },
            success: function ()
            {
                console.log("it Work");
            }
        });

        console.log("It failed");
    })

});
```

This is my route

```
Route::delete('users/destroy', 'UsersController@destroy');
```

this is my controller

```
public function destroy()
{
    $id = input::get('id');
    $id = User::findorfail($id);
    $id->delete();
}
```

This the errror I get

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:\

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 CSRF form submit through Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444236/laravel-4-csrf-form-submit-through-ajax-call)

Comment: The base URL of the page that launches the ajax should match exactly the location the ajax is hitting.  Can you verify that your main page is on the same domain? http://localhost:8888

Comment: FYI, you should only use IDs on elements if they are single elements. You should apply the `destroy` class to them rather than ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `&_token={{ csrf_token() }}`in data array after `id` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

View

```html
<td>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>" name="_token">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="destroy" data-id="5"><i class="fa   fa-trash-o "></i>
    </button> </td>
```

Script

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#destroy").click(function()
    {

        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "http://localhost:8888/users/destroy",
            type: 'DELETE',
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {
              "_token": token,
                "id": id,

            },
            success: function ()
            {
                console.log("it Work");
            }
        });

        console.log("It failed");
    })

});
```