# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php while JQuery Ajax

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**Below is the code in Blade.**

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">

@foreach($Projects as $Project)
    <tr>
        <td>
            @if($Project->ProjectStatusID == \App\Enumeration\Project\ProjectStatus::Open)
                <a pid="{!! $Project->ProjectID !!}" class="Shutmedown" >Cancel</a>
            @endif
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.Shutmedown').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/CancelProject",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"ProjectID" : $(this).attr('pid')},
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('hi');
        }
    });
});
```

### **What's the Problem ?**

JQuery Ajax gives error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

**On checking more details about the request: I got below error details.**

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

**Am I missing something ?**

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444236/laravel-4-csrf-form-submit-through-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

Hi as of Laravel documentation the token must be injected to the backend on ajax requests using a header. So they suggest putting the token in a meta field, eg.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And doing this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

To send the token to the backend via header.

I hope it helps.

So in your case, on the ajax request pass the value of the input that holds the token.